# Does Silverlight 4 have cross platform native process calling?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there anything in Silverlight 4 that's comparable to Adobe AIR 2's beta Native Process API? I need to be able to call native executables on different OS platforms and can't seem to find any easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it exists for now.